# Dashboard to summarize data from specific tab in workbook

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet that tracks all payments received daily. Each month is separated by tabs. Im creating a dashboard where you can use a drop downlist to select a month, then the daily totals for that month(tab) would populate in the rows below.

[image]

issues: My formulas are not recognizing the drop down menu text, I need to create a list of the days of the month based on the drop down selection month (ex December), then I need it to summarize the total amounts by day

[image]

[image]

for Dates column, I tried to start reference the drop down box and concatenate the day and year, but it wont read the drop down box as text so that didnt work. I was then going to sumifs the dates based on the drop down selected month and tab data. But I cant get that to work if i cant get the dates to waterfall based on selected month.

Comment: You may need `INDIRECT()` function. It is good practice to store all raw data in one tab. Then you can easily filter, summarize your data based on date, months, years from that  tab. That would be more efficient way.